# jQuery dialog scripts for input val

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, dialog, modal-dialog

I have a bit of a problem with a jQuery dialog and the way scripts are handled.

In the dialog html, I have

```
<input id="test">
```

If I do

```
<script type="text/javascript>
   $('#test').val("haha")
</script>
```

***after*** the input, it shows up. If I put it ***before***, it doesn't work.
Now the problem is I'm trying to change the value of $('#test') using a click trigger, and I can't!

```
   $('.testbutton').click(function() { 
          alert();      
          $('#test').val("haha");
    });
```

The alert works, and the initial val replacement works, which means there aren't any duplicate or missing input areas.

The total script as it is now, not working:

```
<input type="button" class="testbutton" />
<input type="text" size="10" id="test" name="test" value="">

 $('#test').val("currentvalue"); // This works
       $('.testbutton').click(function() { 
              alert();      
              $('#test').val("haha");
        });
```

**Update**
The dialog shows the correct value in #test once the dialog is closed and then reopened. Could this be something I'm missing?

Comment: Are u sure `val()` is right here? Afaik its for `<select />` not `<input />`. Try `attr("value")`

Comment: @ZeissS - `val()` works fine for inputs

Comment: Indeed, `val()` is best. `attr('value')` happens to work for inputs because it translates to JavaScript `.value` on the HTMLInputElement node. It *does not* access the HTML attribute `value`, which is a completely different thing: the attribute `value` corresponds to the JavaScript property `.defaultValue`, not `.value`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem ended up being the # in test. For some reason the replacement works with a class identifier instead of a id identifier. I suppose it's because the # will replace only one instance, and for some reason that I have yet to discover, there is more than one instance of the dialog (or a hidden one).

Thanks for all your suggestions!

Answer (score 2):

Put your jQuery code into `$(document).ready(function () {...your code...})`. This will make it executed *after* browser creates DOM tree for your page. Otherwise javascript is not able to search/manipulate DOM elements correctly. It will look as following:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.testbutton').click(function() { 
          $('#test').val("haha");
    });
});
```

**Update:**

If your HTML code is loaded dynamically, then use [`live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) to bind event handler:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.testbutton').live("click", function() { 
          $('#test').val("haha");
    });
});
```

Comment: Well if it's a dialog, it's possible that it's being loaded via AJAX, and that it's an HTML fragment. If that's the case, then there'll be no "ready" event fired for that content.

Comment: Nope, doesn't work. The dialog is a post DOM event anyways, so adding a document.ready inside a dialog doesn't quite make sense, I think?

Comment: The updated version didn't work for me. Does it matter where it's put?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should wrap your code inside of a $(function() { //code here }); to make sure your code is run only when your DOM is ready.

Comment: Again, if the dialog content is an HTML fragment loaded via AJAX, there's no "ready" event. Of course, I don't know that that's how his dialog works, because the original question doesn't describe the environment very well.

Comment: In case you're loading the HTML via AJAX, you should run the bind method after loading the HTML to the DOM, it depends on the specific use case.